# Running kernel: problem installing via conda in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, kernel, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I have a problem with running kernel.
I am trying to install beautifulsoup4 in conda via

`conda install beautifulsoup4`

but it stops at this point

[image]

Does anyone know how I can overcome this problem?

I know, that this means that my kernel is running, but still.

Answer (score 1):

In general I'd recommend installing packages via your terminal/CLI.  It looks like you're using a MacOS, so opening "terminal" and executing the same command:

```
conda install beautifulsoup4
```

will should install the package locally for you.  Likewise, you can also use the `pip` package manager to do this:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

After this you can restart your kernel in your notebook (`kernel -> restart`), and replace your install command with a simple

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup4
```